# hexagonal grid Mouse over

Tags: hexagonal-grid

[image]

I've been trying to workout the code that calculates the correct row and column in the mouse is over event the following is the code I'm using to draw the grid Tile are 64x64.

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
  Dim mDestRect As Rectangle

  Dim mX As Int32 = 0
  Dim mY As Int32 = 0

  Using mFont As New Font("Segoe UI", 7.0F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point)
   Using mBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Black))
    For row As Int32 = 0 To 9
     For column As Int32 = 0 To 9

      If (row Mod 2) = 1 Then
        mX = (column * mTileWidth) + 32
      Else
          mX = column * mTileWidth
      End If

      mY = (row * mTileHeight) - (row * 16)


      mDestRect = New Rectangle(mX, mY, mTile.Width, mTile.Height)
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(mTile, mDestRect, mSrc, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)


     Dim mREct As New Rectangle(mX + mTile.Width * 0.25F, mY + mTile.Height * 0.25F, mTile.Width * 0.5F, mTile.Height * 0.5F)
     e.Graphics.FillEllipse(mBrush, mREct)

     TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, String.Format("[{0},{1}]", column, row), mFont, mDestRect, Color.White, TextFormatFlags.NoPadding Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter)

     Next column
    Next row
   End Using
  End Using
 End Sub
```

can anybody help please

Comment: You shouldn't use the `<code>` tags for multiline code

Comment: [You may find this answer useful](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/100714/39518)

Comment: I tried just to post the code but it did not help either way.DMGregory not really could see what I was looking for in it

Comment: @JasonHowells It's exactly about your problem. IMO this should be closed as duplicate. Also, use a @ before the names, so they get a message that you answered, and read this: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Bálint I'm not sure what you mean, duplicate of what? I'm still not seeing the answer to the question.

Comment: @JasonHowells It's about picking in a hexagonal grid. Your question is about picking in a hexagonal grid -> duplicate